# A Single Set of Double Quotes for Python Comments?

Tags: python, coding-style, comments

While reviewing some code used in the online [CS188.1x](https://www.edx.org/courses/BerkeleyX/CS188.1x/2012_Fall/about) class on edX.org (code written by the instructors), I noticed the repeated use of a single set of double quotes (like one might use around a str) for use as comments.

I haven't seen this before, nor is it mentioned in [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments) that I could find, but it certainly seems to work fine.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Here's an example:

```
class SomeClass():
    """
    Some docstring info, using standard 'triple double quotes'
    """
    def  __init__(self):
        "This is the comment style to which I'm referring."
        some.code = foo      # Here's a normal inline comment

    def bar(self, item):
        "Here is another example of the comment style"
       return wtf
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [docstring](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) is any string literal that appears as the first statement in a class, method, function or module.  Stylistically it's typical and preferred to use the triple quote format to allow for longer, better formatted docstrings, and to call attention to them for easy reference, but any string will qualify.

Docstrings are distinct from comments because comments are not relevant to the execution of a program at all, whereas docstrings are available at runtime by accessing an object's `__doc__` variable.

Answer (score 0):

That's just docstring. It's a good design recommendation. For example, if you load that class in your python shell, you can call a `help(bar)` and you'll get `"Here is another example of the comment style"`